# Why does Valgrind only show ??? in the HEAP SUMMARY?

Tags: c, valgrind, slam, slam-algorithm

I use `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./Monocular-Inertial/mono_inertial_euroc` to check my file, where `./Monocular-Inertial/mono_inertial_euroc` is my file, but the HEAP SUMMARY is something wrong.

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==9189==     in use at exit: 316,622 bytes in 2,183 blocks
==9189==   total heap usage: 2,941 allocs, 758 frees, 482,371 bytes allocated
==9189== 
==9189== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 113 of 671
==9189==    at 0x4C37BFD: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1328)
==9189==    by 0x10D7AC30: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
==9189==    by 0x10B032FE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
==9189==    by 0x10B08530: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
==9189==    by 0x10AE63BE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
==9189==    by 0x10AE0277: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
==9189==    by 0x40108D2: call_init (dl-init.c:72)
==9189==    by 0x40108D2: _dl_init (dl-init.c:119)
==9189==    by 0x40010C9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so)
```

I use `cmake` to compile my file, it need to revise my `CMakelist.txt`,how to do it?

Comment: This is probably harmless. To get more details you need to either install the debuginfo package for `glib` or else get a version of `glib` compiled with debug options.

Comment: @Paul Floyd Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Paul Floyd Thanks for your answer. But there is some questions, in my `Cmakelist.txt`, I add `add_definitions("-Wall -g")` to generate debug info,just like`gcc -g`, bu the valgrind still show ??? . How to install debuginfo package for glib or else get a version of glib compiled with debug options?  I use Ubuntu 18.04.